# the download from your website shows up as a .iso file which does not work for installing

Tags: 14.04

I tried on two different computers, one is my target computer which is a net book, the other is my main computer where I moved this file to a USB drive. The Internet says these are image files that do not execute the way the YouTube videos show they should work.

What do I need to do differently in order to install the Ubuntu software on the net book?

Answer (score 1):

To create a bootable USB for Ubuntu, you can follow this excellent guide from Ubuntu's own website. See [Ubuntu's website for the guide here!](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

I'm guessing that you're a present Windows user, that's why I'll give you a link for the windows guide. If I'm wrong, there should more of these guides for other OS's as well.

Good luck,